Why HasManyThrough does not work with 3 related tables
On laravel 10 site  I have 3 related tables :
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    ...
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
});


Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('creator_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    ...
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
});



Schema::create('task_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

    $table->foreignId('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->unique(['user_id', 'task_id']);
});

Last table is many to many relation which tasks are assigned to which user.
Field tasks.creator_id is different - who created a task.
Model app/Models/User.php have :
public function tasks(): HasManyThrough {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Task::class,
            TaskUser::class,
        );
}

Running request :
    $this->profileUser = User::getById($this->userId)->with('tasks')->first();

I have error :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tasks.task_user_id' in 'on clause'
SELECT
  `tasks`.*,
  `task_users`.`user_id` AS `laravel_through_key`
FROM
  `tasks`
  INNER JOIN `task_users` ON `task_users`.`id` = `tasks`.`task_user_id`
WHERE
  `task_users`.`user_id` IN (1)

Table tasks has no task_user_id field at all. Which syntax is valid ? Must other  Task, TaskUser models have
any other relations ro make my relation working correctly ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",

Thanks in advance!

Are you sure you need a hasManyTrough? Looks more like you need a belongsToMany

have you tried passing the foreign key is your hasManyThrough? check this document
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions

You've got a many-to-many, where task_user is a pivot table between tasks and users. This is not a hasManyThrough. Check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. Also, you generally don't define a Model for a pivot table, so unless you need it, you can probably delete your TaskUser Model.

Sidequestion, what is getById($this->userId)? The find() method exists that does this, so why not User::with('tasks')->find($this->userId);?

Which method have I to use here ? something like belongsToManyThrough ?

Nope, again, read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure. On both your User model you'd define public function tasks(): BelongsToMany { return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class); }, and the same for users(), User::class on your Task model.
